# Populating Gridview Using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax

i have two gridview. on click of one row of one grid i have to populate another gridview. so onClientclick javascript function i called ajax which returns datatable for populating another grid. Now i am stuck how to bind grid view using javascript.

here is code

```
<asp:gridview id="gridview1"> .....</asp:gridview>
<asp:gridview id="gridview2"> .....</asp:gridview>
```

codebehind

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
             LinkButton db = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];

        db.OnClientClick = "FunPopulateSecondGrid(" + CType(CType(e.Row.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Row, Label).text + ");"
            }
}
```

javascript

```
function FunPopulateSecondGrid(productid)
{
   $.ajax({
            url : '...',
            data : { getExEmpList: true, SelectedShop : selectedShop, ajaxCall : true },
            method : 'GET',
            dataType : 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success : function(data) {
// i am stuck here how to bind it
//gridview2.datasource= data
//gridview2.databind()              
            },
            error : function(xhr, status) {
                alert('Sorry, there was a problem while placing your ajax request. Contact Admin!');
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to append the data to gridview in success section like this

If you have gridview  with Id "gridview2"

```
function FunPopulateSecondGrid(productid)
    {
       $.ajax({
                url : '...',
                data : { getExEmpList: true, SelectedShop : selectedShop, ajaxCall : true },
                method : 'GET',
                dataType : 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 success: function (data) { //you need to append the data to gridview
             for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    $("#gridview2").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].ProductName + 
                                                "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Price + "</td></tr>");
                 },
                error : function(xhr, status) {
                    alert('Sorry, there was a problem while placing your ajax request. Contact Admin!');
                }
            });
    }
```

Please find complete solution here :[Bind GridView with Jquery](http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/archive/2010/10/30/bind-gridview-using-jquery.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here Scott Guthrei blog "Tip/Trick: Cool UI Templating Technique to use with ASP.NET AJAX for non-UpdatePanel scenarios", this is exact sample for which you are looking.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/10/22/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Cool-UI-Templating-Technique-to-use-with-ASP.NET-AJAX-for-non_2D00_UpdatePanel-scenarios.aspx

**Note:** Here he use asp.net ajax with script manager but you can replace that portion with jQuery ajax.

Comment: i have datatable in javascript which was return from ajax and i want to assign it to grid view. this didnt help me and besides my both grids are in updatepanel

Comment: GridView is server side control and you can not directly bind it on client side using DataSource and DataBind(), you have to do that at server side and resulting html you need to pass to client and put in container